# Parsing HTML href attribute

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm working on a project where i need to parse HTML for extracting data from a webpage. I'm using Jsoup in Java. I need to extract data from the following contents.

```
<tr>
            <td><small><a href="http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=20160821T2100&amp;p1=248" target="_blank">2016/08/21 21:00</a></small></td>
            <td><small><a href="https://agc003.contest.atcoder.jp">AtCoder Grand Contest 003</a></small></td>

</tr>
```

I can get the value Contest name and Time but how to extract the URL. I want to get the contest URL `https://agc003.contest.atcoder.jp`
how to get this ??

**EDIT:**
Here's my code

```
private void getAC() throws IOException {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://atcoder.jp/").userAgent(Desktop.getDesktop().toString()).get();
    Element table = doc.getElementsByClass("table-responsive").get(1);
    Elements contestStartTime = table.getElementsByTag("td");
    int cnt = 1;
    for (Element i : contestStartTime) {
        System.out.println(cnt + ". " + i.html());
        cnt++;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSoup or Java but I would load the file, read it line by line and use a regex pattern to search for the <td>'s you require, then parse the Url from that line.

Comment: Can you add your code for getting the contest name and time?

Comment: Since the tags dont seem to have an id or anyhing to target them with, I'm not really sure. However, to get the URL once you find the element is easy. `Elements.attr("href")` should get you the value

Comment: using i.attr("href")  prints nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSoup have rich api for DOM processing, look for this functions:

```
Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

Also you can get your links this way

```
Elements links = doc.select("table a[href]");
```